# Current across a wire with zero potential difference

Tags: voltage, current, resistors

If there was a circuit connected with a \$50 \,\Omega\$ resistor and a \$5 \, \rm V\$ battery and we measured the voltage across two points of the wire that have no resistor or battery, does it mean the voltage is zero? Then, according to \$V = I R\$, is the current also zero?

Assume that the wire has negligible resistance.

Comment: Current is **through** the wire.  Voltage is measured **across** two points.

Comment: In the limit, \$I=\frac{V}{R}=\frac{0}{0} \$, which is indeterminate.

Comment: NB you might find it difficult to have an ideal wire with no resistance at all in practice, even low temperature superconductors have some.

Comment: What is the smallest voltage you can measure, and how does it compare to 'negligable'?

Comment: @eckes from wikipedia: "Superconductivity is a phenomenon of *exactly zero* electrical resistance"

Answer (score 23):

> [in a plain wire] does it mean the voltage is zero?

Yes, the voltage across both ends of an ideal wire is always zero.

> [given U = R * I] is the current also zero?

No, it means that the current can have an arbitrary value. Because in ...

```
0 V = 0 Ohm * x Ampere
```

... x can have any value.

Comment: Theoretically, current can be any value but in practice there's melting point of wire's material. So send enough amps and the wire will melt.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy but it won't: P=R*I^2, 0W=0Ω*(x A)^2, x can have any value.

Comment: @user60561  Well, theoretically, yes. But here's [500 Amp vs wrench](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJOX0c60wQE)

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy 100000A over 0Ω: https://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2014-07/nion-mff072514.php. The actual current is passed through those two 5mm by 20mm superconductors.

Comment: @user60561 Well that's just cheating with superconductors :) JK. Interesting article. Thanks.

Comment: However, no real wire is ideal, and exhibits resistance along its length ... but the voltage drop across this tiny resistance measures very, very small, and we usually treat that as zero volts. While "0 V = 0 Ohm * x Ampere" is definately true, it doesn't hold as all wire has resistance (well, except superconductors).

Answer (score 4):

If you connect a 5 V voltage source with a 50 Ohm resistor, there will be a current of:

$$ I = U/R = 0.1 \ A $$

Even if you measure a voltage of 0 Volt between two spots with a resistance of (almost) 0 Ohm between them, there is still a current of 0.1 A. It's simply a problem of measurement accuracy: As the resistance decreases, so does the voltage you can measure.

Let's say the Ohmic resistance is not zero but 1 nano-Ohm, then you would expect a voltage of:

$$ V = R \cdot I = 1 \ n\Omega \cdot 0.1 \ A = 100 \ pV $$

Of course, measuring such a voltage of 100 pico-Volt would be a challenge.

Comment: OP specifically mentioned the wire between the measuring points had a resistance of zero. It is clearly a theoretical question so this answer is therefore incorrect

Comment: @MCG: No, please read the question again! In fact, this answer clarifies what it implies to have a "negligible resistance" without talking about mathematical limits.

Comment: You need to read it again. The measurement is taking place over a bit of wire with zero resistance. The e-cell with the negligible resistance and the 50 ohm resistor are at different places of the circuit. The measurement is over **zero** ohms. So again. This is incorrect

Comment: @MCG: Where do you read zero?

Comment: I think it's clear what the OP means if you read the question properly. The answer by nikolai answers perfectly

Comment: @MCG: I also think I understand clearly what the OP thinks, but apparently it's not the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90247/discussion-between-frank-from-frankfurt-and-mcg).

Comment: Not much point in having a discussion about it in a chat. Can't see it being a productive use of anyones time in all honestly. You will say one thing, I will say another and it goes back and forth. Pointless discussion.

Comment: @MCG: Well, let's continue to spam comments!

Comment: I'd like to simply mention that *it's good to discuss the differences between an ideal wire and a non-ideal one*. The OP doesn't have the a full understanding, hence the question. Making the distinction between the two points out that while we normally treat these as ideal wires, *they are not*. While troubleshooting some kind of faults, this knowledge is crucial.